# Amazon S3 was not found in region metadata

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I 'm trying to build the [S3 Transfer Manager Demo](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/S3_TransferManager) , but when I run the application I am getting the following error , already researched several alternatives but really I am not able to solve this error .

```
{cognito-identity, us-west-2} was not found in region metadata, 
trying to construct an endpoint 
using the standard pattern for this region: 'cognito-identity.us-west-2.amazonaws.com'.
```

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Amazon Cognito Identity](http://aws.amazon.com/cognito/) is currently available only in the US East region. Please refer to [Regions and Endpoints](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#cognito_identity_region) for more details.

Please note that even if you use Amazon Cognito Identity in US East Region, the credentials can be used in other AWS regions (except the AWS China (Beijing) Region).